# How do I configure Struts 2 with Tomcat 6?

Tags: java, xml, web-applications, tomcat, struts

Can anyone help me to configure struts 2.0.14 (I'm using tomcat 6.0). I want to know what is the procedure to build my first application in struts. Also tell me how xml is used to build a struts application. I have tried and tired of Google and that's why I'm here. Please suggest some nice tutorials for struts from your own experience.

Comment: I like your felicitous but probably unintentional 'tried and tired' phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Look here [Struts 2 Tutorials for Beginners](http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/index.shtml) that should help you on the way.
They also explain the xml in Struts 2.

Answer (score 0):

What was wrong or missing from the material at the [Struts home page](http://struts.apache.org/)?  There are links to information for beginners, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you can find more information about Struts 2 tutorials at http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/how-to-create-a-struts-2-web-application.html

Basically, this is the same documentation, that is also available as a part of any Struts 2.x release.
There are few sample web application code -zip also available that you can build using Ant or Maven.